# Problema ao retornar de um CustonAlertDialog - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um CustonAlertDialog que faz uma salva uma informação no banco, para isso, ao clicar no botão de ENVIAR eu uso um await. A informação é salva no banco com sucesso, porém a aplicação trava e não executa o comando para fechar o Alert "Navigator.pop".

```
class ConfirmarPresencaWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<bool> parentAction;
  ConfirmarPresencaController controller = Modular.get();

  ConfirmarPresencaWidget({Key key, this.parentAction}) : super(key: key);
  //var mask = MaskedTextController(mask: '(00) 0 0000.0000');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: new Text("Confirme sua presença"),
      content: Container(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              //*NOME E SOBRENOME
              TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  controller.nome = value;
                  controller.checkIsValid();
                },
                maxLength: 30,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Nome e sobrenome',
                    counterStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)),
              ),
              //* TELEFONE
              TextField(
                //TODO verificar possível troca da máscara: parece não ter suporte WEB
                //controller: mask,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  controller.telefone = value;
                  controller.checkIsValid();
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Telefone',
                    counterStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
              ),
              //* QUANTIDADE DE ADULTOS E CRIANCAS
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('adultos'),
                      QuantidadeInputWidget(
                        parentAction: controller.setAdultos,
                        value: 1,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('crianças'),
                      QuantidadeInputWidget(
                        parentAction: controller.setCriancas,
                        value: 0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        //* define os botões na base do dialogo
        RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: new Text("Cancelar"),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        Observer(builder: (_) {
          return RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: new Text("Enviar"),
            onPressed: controller.isValid
                ? () async {
                    var result = await controller.enviarConfirmacao();

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                : null,
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: E o código do controller.enviarConfirmacao()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando o `await` portanto, o seu método ficará bloqueado aguardando até que o `Future` retornado pelo `controller.enviarConfirmacao()` seja completado. Para só então executar a próxima instrução, que é fechar o dialog.

Você não colocou o código desse método, mas me parece que ele não está retornando nada, não completando o seu `Future`. E ele deve retornar.

Tente pensar em uma solução melhor pois desta forma você está congelando a tela para o usuário sem um loading ou qualquer informação de que tem um processamento sendo feito.

Comment: Obrigado. Realmente, o problema foi o retorno desse método.